# SQL Server 2005 Blocking Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, locking

I am experiencing a blocking issue in sql server 2005. An end user executes a query (e.g.  select statements) and seems to get into a never-ending blocking until i kill the process e.g. for hours on end .

the end user querys run just fine when I test the. It seems to get into a blocking issue when qanother process tries to truncate and reload a table.

how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: If it is `SELECT`-ing from a table that has been `TRUNCATE`-d by another still open transaction then yes it will be blocked. Are you saying the blocking continues even after that other transaction is completed?

Comment: No its a select statemetn that normally runs (e.g. when i test it) in < 30 minutes, but it sometimes runs endlessly (and while it is running endlessly, it prevents a nightly etl process from truncating a table).  I guess i should be looking into why it runs forever, and that would solve the overall issue.

Comment: Ah I see. Well I guess either the `SELECT` is itself blocked by something else (look in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks`) or sometimes it gets a catastrophically bad plan that means it is actually doing much more work (e.g. parameter sniffing). You say "the end user querys run just fine when I test" so sounds like the second one. Compare and contrast the execution plans from both sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I look at it is, right click on the database in SSMS and under Reports => Standard Reports => All Blocking Transactions. There are other standard reports with blocking transactions as well but I found all one pretty useful.

The other thing you could do is setup a SQL Server Agent Alert for figuring our locks for your database.

Type: SQL server performance condition alert
Object: SQL Server:Locks
Counter: Anything you want
Instance: Database
Rises above: {x} number of occurrences you want to look for.

And have the alert set to email you when the condition is met (considering you have Database Mail setup already).